# Font not changing in CSS even after importing

Tags: html, css, fonts

I created a folder for all my fonts. Here's my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Play with bulb!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

   <img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="images/lightOff.gif">

   <h1 id="myText" onclick="changeText()"></h1>

</body>
</html>
```

And my CSS:

```
@import url("./fonts/Poppins-ExtraBold.ttf");

#myText {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
}
```

I also have a javascript file, but I'm not giving it as it is unrelated to this question.

For some reason, it isn't showing Poppins. Any reason why it isn't?
I even checked in the inspect tab, and it showed this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`@import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import) is for importing CSS, not font files.

You need [`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) to load a custom font.

> ```
> @font-face {
>   font-family: "Open Sans";
>   src: url("/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"),
>        url("/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff") format("woff");
> }
> ```

And then you can use it with the name you defined:

```
#myText {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
```

Comment: I added this to my CSS:
```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Poppins";
  src: url("/fonts/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf") format("ttf"),
       url("/fonts/Poppins-ExtraLightItalic.ttf") format("ttf");
}
```

Comment: But still it isn't changing :(

Comment: See the linked documentation, the format name for Truetype fonts is `truetype`, not `ttf`

Answer (score 1):

Try using this css:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Poppins' ;
   src: url('./fonts/Poppins-ExtraBold.ttf') format('truetype');
}

#myText {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
}
```

Comment: I added this to my CSS:
@font-face {
  font-family: "Poppins";
  src: url("/fonts/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf") format("true type"),
       url("/fonts/Poppins-ExtraLightItalic.ttf") format("true type");
}
Still, it isn't changing :(

Comment: It is `truetype` not `true type`